# WPF Template Binding Path.Fill

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate

I have the following sytles:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowButtonTriggers" TargetType="Button">            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MinimizeButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowButtonTriggers}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="appbar_minus" Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0" Background="Transparent" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                        <Rectangle Width="24" Height="4" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="24" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>                        
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CloseButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowButtonTriggers}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="appbar_close" Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0" Background="Transparent">
                        <Path Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="14" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Data="F1 M 17,14L 24,21L 30.9999,14.0001L 33.9999,17.0001L 27,24L 33.9999,31L 31,34L 24,27L 17,34L 14,31L 21,24L 14,17L 17,14 Z "/>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When I create a button with the style "MinimizeButton" it works fine (when the mouse is over the button color changes) but when I create a button with the style "CloseButton" it doesn't work and I don't understand why since they are almost the same style.

Any help is greatly appreciated

*Edit*

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <my:Menu Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#FF777777"/>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,0">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MinimizeButton}" />            
        <Button Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" Command="Close" />      
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show the XAML where you consume these styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it is not working is because the Close command and CanExcecute is not defined which then sets the IsEnabled property on the button to false. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.close.aspx) states that

> There is not necessarily an implementation for the command on any given object; in many cases the implementation for the command is the responsibility of the application writer.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) is a good article on Code Project to get you started on working with WPF Commands.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem :)